# Convert bootstrap colums to tab in mobile view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 tab1">
            <div class="title">Content</div>
<div>content1 content2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 tab2">
            <div class="title">user</div>
<div>user1 user2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this the code im using for responsiveness now my client want in mobile this should work as tab. kindly help me to sort this out.

Comment: Why will anyone want to have something to look like tab to work in mobile? What is the actual requirement?

Comment: Why not use an accordion?

Comment: as per the responsiveness in mobile mode it should act as tab instead of stack

Comment: Bootstrap is designed to stack columns on a mobile device, which is the preferred behaviour. They will not simply turn into tabs by applying any of the default classes. You would need to code this yourself in JS. See [tabs in bootstrap](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/nav-tabs-and-pills-tutorial.php)

Comment: got the answer and mentioned below..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using bootstrap 4 classes only:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs d-sm-none">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#a">Panel A</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#b">Panel B</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#c">Panel C</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content d-flex">
        <div id="a" class="flex-grow-1 d-sm-block tab-pane active bg-primary">
            <div>content Panel A</div>
            <div>content Panel A</div>
            <div>content Panel A</div>
            <div>content Panel A</div>
        </div>
        <div id="b" class="flex-grow-1 d-sm-block tab-pane bg-secondary">
            <div>content Panel B</div>
            <div>content Panel B</div>
            <div>content Panel B</div>
            <div>content Panel B</div>
        </div>
        <div id="c" class="flex-grow-1 d-sm-block tab-pane bg-success">
            <div>content Panel C</div>
            <div>content Panel C</div>
            <div>content Panel C</div>
            <div>content Panel C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all i got the solution with out using extra js,

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs device-small" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="home">...home...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="profile">...profile...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="messages">...messages...</div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Style is

```
/* --------------- Responsive Fixes --------------- */
        /* small device */
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .device-big {
            display: none;
            }
            .device-small {
            display: block;
            }
        }
        /* big device */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
            .device-big, .tab-content > .tab-pane {
            display: block;
            }
            .device-small {
            display: none;
            }
            .tab-content > .tab-pane {
                display: block;
            }
        }
        /* --------------- / Responsive Fixes --------------- */
```